# efficient set operations in google app engine datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm having problems converting a set problem into an efficient google app engine datastore solution. The problem is as follows. I have an entity defining a relationship between two objects, i.e. something like this:

```
struct Relation
{
  Obj1 int
  Obj2 int

  // other data
}
```

Now I want to perform the following query in an efficient manner: given a set of objects `set = [obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4]`, I want to find all Relation entities (`E`) for which `E.Obj1 ∈ set ∧ E.Obj2 ∈ set`. Note that I do not know the set beforehand, so I cannot precompute all the entries in the set once. Is there any way to represent this problem in the datastore so that I can efficiently retrieve all the relationships that are part of a given set?

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent GQL query is "SELECT * FROM Kind WHERE Obj1 IN :1 AND Obj2 IN :1", passing in the set as the first parameter. Unfortunately, IN queries expand out to one query for each term, so there's a combinatorial explosion of queries here - 16 queries in the case of a 4 element set. There's not really any way to avoid this with a standard query.

Comment: Of course I can do that, but that is exactly not what I want :)

Comment: @jessevdk Unfortunately, there's no magical recipe to get around it - that's just how indexing works.